# DevExpress Date Picker Without Day

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I want to catch the event when the date is picked up
and when the day pick appear the control should close
(I just want to select the year and month **but not the day**)

and show on text just the month and the year (display value)

if this is possible
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been a number of questions/posts about this and various DevExpress controls.  I am not sure if you are looking at winforms, asp, etc... but so far as I am aware this is a feature still not built in to the devexpress controls.

Here is [one of those posts](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ60183.aspx), that includes an example solution of a popupcontainer control to accomplish that task in winforms.

Answer (score 3):

On DevExpress 12.2 this task can be accomplished by set `DateEdit` => `Properties` => `VistaCalendarViewStyle` to `YearView, YearsGroupView, CenturyView`.

I don't know wether it applicable to lower version or not.